# How to display data on the bottom of the spreadsheet using spreadsheet gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, ruby, spreadsheet

I am using spreadsheet gem to exact data into a spreadsheet. The sheet shows the correct data in rows and columns. The issue I am facing here is I want to add additional data at the bottom of the spreadsheet as below and I am not able to figure out how to do that. Below is the code and how the spreadsheet should look.

```
def download
  headers = ['User Name', 'Type']

  content_stream = StringIO.new

  # Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
  workbook = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
  users_sheet = workbook.create_worksheet name: 'Users'

  users_sheet.row(0).concat(headers)

  format = Spreadsheet::Format.new(weight: :bold)

  users_sheet.row(0).default_format = format
  @users = User.all
  @users.each.with_index(1) do |user, index|
    users_sheet.row(index).push user.full_name,
                                user.type
  end
  auto_fit(users_sheet)
  workbook.write(content_stream)
  content_stream.rewind

  send_data(content_stream.read, filename: "users.xls")
end

private

def auto_fit(sheet)
  (0...sheet.column_count).each do |col_idx|
    column = sheet.column(col_idx)
    column.width = column.each_with_index.map do |cell, row|
      chars = cell.present? ? cell.to_s.strip.split('').count + 4 : 1
      ratio = sheet.row(row).format(col_idx).font.size / 10
      (chars * ratio).round
    end.max
  end
end
```

Right now the spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

How it should look:

[image]

Comment: You just need to "push" that data the same way you are handling the rest. e.g. `users_sheet.row(3).push("Total: $2000")` where this data comes from is not clear in your question.

Comment: @engineersmnky here you have hard coded row(3), what if there are more than rows, and total and current are the fields I have calculated in the user model. Just hardcoding it above in my question.

Comment: `@users.size + 1` should work.